# hide image path possible with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I got image path like that http://blablablabla.com/Admin/img/blablabla.jpg but i do not want to show this path user can i hide this URL with `htaccess` ?

**For example :** user will see path like that http://blablablabla.com/Info/img/blablabla.jpg but i have not Info folder this is possible ? so i do not want to see users never see my images paths is way is useful or not i'm not sure tell your ideas which way to most secure to hide my path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting your url will not make a difference security-wise. If the only security you have is hoping that no-one will ever know that a certain folder exists, then you have no security at all.

The requested rewrite can be done by placing the following directives in a `.htaccess` file in the www-root of your website.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Info/img/([^/]+)$ Admin/img/$1 [L]
```

This is an internal rewrite that rewrites the url that is requested to an internal url that points to an actual file. `$1` is replaced by the first capture group. See the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information.