# Use Htaccess / php to hide image true URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I run several websites who show the same pictures. I'd like to host them on a "source" website and call them into each one of the "target" sites.

But I don't want to show an external URL in the image HREF. I'd like to rebuild them with htaccess or php.

I tried using htaccess rewriting/PHP header function but with no luck. The "source" site would be on the same server.

For instance. I host xxx.jpg on "source_site.com/image_source/" and on the target site, every image with href like "target_site/common_images/xxx.jpg would be actually show the site_source image, but with a local href. Is it possible ?

Also, just another question. If I succeed in doing what I want, would the "cloaked" image be cached by cloudflare as a regular image ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Info/img/([^/]+)$ Admin/img/$1 [L]
```

for more refer [hide image path possible with htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930254/hide-image-path-possible-with-htaccess)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !
But, are you sure it works for external domains ?
I don't want to redirect to an image that is on the same website, but to an image that is on the same server, but on another website.