# How do I hide the image src path by using .htaccess in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I need to hide image src path by using .htaccess because any one can download the image by using firebug and see the actual path

Comment: How will that help keep people from downloading the image? With Chrome you can simply right click the image and do `Save Image as`. I don't see how trying to hide src will matter.

Comment: if broswe can see it, i can download it, the browser is actully downloading it anyway

Comment: Oke i got it but suppose i have a some videos and videos has a membership for view so how can i restrict.. that time any one can see the video path and download it..but video has a membership..please let me know

Comment: One method i can suggest is don't load the video from the link directly. instead use a script which validates the credentials and if it is fine read the file and send to the browser. you can use [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: Then you need to use an authentication system. Like having a members area not available to someone without a valid account. You need read up on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide image path possible with htaccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930254/hide-image-path-possible-with-htaccess)

Comment: Disable right click and show fake url on mouse hover.

Answer (score 1):

its not possible to hide img src but you can show fake url by htaccess . and if your wish is to restrict users from stealing your images by hiding the image source,its not possible because  if a user can see the image on their browser, then it means the user has downloaded the image and it is already on their computer. they can download it by right click and save option .  Simple is that. There is no way to prevent images from being stolen.